# Question on notation of $\mathbb{F}[t]$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

I'm reading an article by Dan Carmon on square-free values of polynomials in function field and I came upon a theorem which I don't fully understand.

It said the following:

> Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of primes in A (i.e. monic, irreducible polynomials). For any $D\in A$, let $\rho(D):= \#\{a \pmod D:f(a) \equiv 0 \pmod D\}, ||D||:=\#\{a \pmod D\} = q^{\deg D}$, and $c_f:= \prod_{P\in \mathcal{P}} \left( 1 - \frac{\rho(P^2)}{||P^2||}\right)$. Then $$\#\{a \in \mathbb{F}_q[t]:\deg_t(a) < m,\quad f(a)\; \text{square-free}\} = c_fq^m+o(q^m)$$ as $m$ tends to $\infty$.

Before this theorem, the article defined:

- Fix a prime power $q$, let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements and let $A = \mathbb{F}_q[t]$ be the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$. $c_f$ is the density function of square free values.

My questions are the following:

- It defined $\mathbb{F}_q$ to be the finite field with $q$ elements, is this equal to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{q\mathbb{Z}}$?
- Does $A$ represent the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q = \{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$
- Why is the meaning of the set of primes in $A$ equal to monic, irreducible polynomials?
- Since $D \in A$, what does it mean when he talks about $a\pmod D$

Any answers would be very helpful

Comment: I think you need to take a big step back and read a lot more background stuff. What finite fields look like and the theory of rings of polynomials seem like absolute prerequisites here.

Comment: Any advice where to start?

Comment: I think most books on introductory abstract algebra will cover these things.

Comment: Alright I will, thank you. I take it that my questions here are incorrect then?

Comment: @Di-lemma Your questions are not incorrect (your guess that $\Bbb F_q\cong \Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$ is only true when $q$ is a prime, though). Maybe it just seems very ambitious to tackle that theorem without some knowledge and experience with finite fields (beyond their mere definition). But please do not feel discouraged to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : the questions are not incorrect but there seems to be a gap between what you want to read and your acquaintance with the field. Maybe you might want to think of $q$ to be prime instead of a prime power, when you read the article.

- No $\mathbb{F}_q$ is not defined as $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{q\mathbb{Z}}$ (if $q$ is not prime but a prime power, the latter is not even an integral domain whereas the former is a field).

> To construct $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, you take an irreducible polynomial $P(X)$ of degree $k$ with coefficients in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ and then define : $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}:=\frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]}{(P(X))}$. You can also define it as the field generated by the roots of $X^{p^k}-1$ inside the algebraic closure of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$.

- $A$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$.
- $A$ is a commutative unitary ring (you have sum and product for polynomials). It is also an integral domain. So you have a notion of prime elements in $A$ (for the record $p\in A$ is prime if any time $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$). He is simply saying that a set of representative (i.e. modulo. multiplication by an invertible element) prime elements can be chosen to be the set of polynomials that are monic and irreducible.
- $a$ mod $D$ means the natural projection of $a\in A$ to the quotient ring $A/(D)$. If you know the Euclidean division for polynomials, it is kind of harmless if you want to have some intuition to think of "$a$ mod $D$" as the remainder in the Euclidean division of $a$ by $D$. In the same spirit,  saying  $a=b$ mod $D$ is equivalent to $D$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: Alright, so I've spent my morning brushing up on fields and polynomial rings, and some other questions arose.

- What exactly is the meaning of $\frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]}{(P(X))}$? I know that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$ is the set of polynomials with integer mod p coefficients. What does it then mean to divide this set by P(X) (is the meaning then mod P(X)?)

Comment: @Di-lemma, I am not dividing a set by the polynomial $P(X)$. I am dividing the ring $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$ by the ideal generated by $P(X)$. This is related to a general algebraic construction, when you have a ring $A$ and an ideal $I$ of $A$ you can always construct the quotient ring $A/I$.

Comment: @Di-lemma, the thing is that you have this general quotient ring construction but concretely, to understand, compute inside this ring you will do as if you were in $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}[X]$ but identify two elements which are equal mod $P(X)$ that is if $P(X)$ divides their difference (if you understand computations inside  $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$, this is the exact same principle).

Comment: @Di-lemma For instance let us take $p=2$ and $k=3$. That is we are going to work the construction of the field with $8$ elements. 1) Show that $P(X)=X^3+X+1$ is irreducible in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}[X]$ (Hint: does it have a root?). 2) Make a list of representative in $\mathbb{F}_8$. 3) Find an element of multiplicative order $7$.